# Notifications stored in redis

Tags: redis

I've been wondering recently how can I store my notifications for users at my mini social network (you can think of it as facebook notifications). They get created once and never change. There will be a lot of them.

I will need to query them by user and order by created date.

Looks like some kind of NoSql solution would do, and I want to try redis. But since I never used it before and I have no idea what data structures should I use and how to use theme effectively.

Thanks for help!

Comment: And also please tell me if my approach is entirely wrong and I need some another solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redis is a perfect fit for this use case.
Use a [sorted set](http://redis.io/commands#sorted_set) for each user to be notified, with a unix timestamp as score.

You could give each sorted set a key built on a pattern like:
`user:<user id>:notifications`

To add a notification for a given user:

```
ZADD <current_unix_timestamp> user:<user_id>:notifications "some notification"
```

Then use [ZREVRANGEBYSCORE](http://redis.io/commands/zrevrangebyscore) to get the recent notifications

```
ZREVRANGEBYSCORE user:<user id>:notifications +inf <last_visit_timestamp>
```

Or if you want all notifications for this user, from the newest to the oldest :

```
ZREVRANGEBYSCORE user:<user id>:notifications +inf -inf
```

**Update:** don't forget that Redis is by default an in-memory database; you may loose some notifications if a crash occurs between two writings on disk. The frequency of write operations is defined in the redis.conf file. If notifications are critical for you, and you can't rebuild them after a crash:
* either consider using 2 Redis instances, a slave and a master, monitored by Redis Sentinel;
* or turn the write settings to "save on disk on every write operation", but that means you will lose speed;
* or use another database.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I'll try to implement this approach

Comment: @YanisT: I added more general information as you may have some bad surprises in case of a crash.